# in-place removal of log lines with old timestamps

Tags: text-processing, sed

Good Day.  I have a log file that I would like to delete lines that are over 30 days old.

**File Contents:**

```
2017/04/04 15:53:22 [11487] building file list
2017/04/04 15:53:22 [11487] done
2017/04/04 15:53:22 [11487] sent 163 bytes  received 12 bytes  350.00 bytes/sec
2017/04/04 15:53:22 [11487] total size is 48640  speedup is 277.94
2017/04/04 15:53:29 [11493] building file list
2017/04/04 15:53:29 [11493] done
```

Attempted using awk, but it doesn't let you perform inline edits on the file.  Also can't use gawk as a solution as I only have v 3.7.0  Was hoping someone can assist with sed perhaps?  Looking for a one liner preferably.  This is in bash.

Comment: *one-liner* in such case would look cumbersome. I would suggest bash solution

Comment: Agreed, perhaps a bash solution is what I should do. This is what I started with:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} {command="date -d \""$1"\" +'%s'";command |getline;close(command);print}'` _file_

Do you know a quick solution in bash?

Comment: This can actually get too easy: `grep -v "$(date '+%Y/%m/%d' -d '30 days ago')*" logfile`

Comment: @val0x00ff, that would pull in lines that are 31 days old or older

Comment: @iruvar I just dived into date's manual. The best option would be to hard code the string then.

Comment: Is `perl` an option? The [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~esaym/Time-Piece-1.31/Piece.pm) module can parse and subtract dates for example.

Comment: @val0x00ff you're funny :)  I'm trying out that oneliner... >steeldriver perl is always an option, but prefer bash

Comment: @val0x00ff Unfortunately it doesn't work!  It would only print the File Contents when I set --date to "25 days ago"

Comment: @AfroJoe the `-v` flag there is to `NOT SHOW` the lines that match the pattern ..`date..`.  So you probably are confusing that.

Comment: @val0x00ff Bam!

Comment: `Bam!` means all ok?

Comment: @val0x00ff This is a very clever solution. You should make this an answer.

Comment: @val0x00ff I would love to make your answer THE answer.. but don't you have to mark it as a solution?

Comment: @AfroJoe you can write an answer yourself and mark it as solution.  Thanks @ George Vasiliou

Comment: `bash` is a shell, a command-line interpreter. Its job is to run commands (`echo`, `date`, `awk`, `perl` or other).

Comment: Similar to [Read log file between two dates](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/76805)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -v "$(date '+%Y/%m/%d' -d '30 days ago')*" logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure that there will be at least one entry for each day, you can say:

```
sed -n '\|'$(date +'%Y/%m/%d' -d '30 days ago')'|,$p' log
```

Provided you have GNU `sed`. If not, you need to escape the slashes in the date.

Comment: That's standard and not GNU-specific

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `sed` part was standard. The `date` part is GNU-specific. I'd quote the `$(...)` (`'\|'"$(date...)"'|,$p'`) so it still works in contexts where $IFS may contain `/` or digits (IOW, there's no reason you'd want to split+glob it here).

Answer (score 0):

If you have `perl`:

```
perl -MPOSIX -ni -e '
  BEGIN{$cutoff = strftime("%Y/%m/%d %T", localtime(time - 30*86400))}
  print if $_ ge $cutoff' file.log
```

If you have GNU `date`:

```
file=file.log
{
  rm -f -- "$file" &&
    awk -v "cutoff=$(date -d '30 days ago' '+%Y/%m/%d %T')" '
      $0 >= cutoff' > "$file"
} < "$file"
```

Both on several lines for clarity, but feel free to put then on one line if that's what you need (you'll need a `;` between `file.log` and `{` and between `"$file"` and `}` when joining the lines of the `awk` variant.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dateadd` and `dategrep` from [dateutils](https://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils/):

```
dategrep  -i "%Y/%m/%d %T" ">=$(dateadd now -30d)" </path/to/logfile
```

`dateadd` calculates the datetime from now to 30 days in the past. Then `dategrep` only prints lines from stdin which contain a date string newer or equal (`>=`) than that. The date format of the log lines needs to be specified by `-i` in this case.

Comment: Can you please extend, clarify your answer?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I've added some text, hope this helps. `dategrep` is basically similar like `grep` especially made to grep for dates and times.